# Replace f:facet by property with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xhtml

I'm trying to convert by XSLT this XML :

```
<app:formField type="display" styleClass="col-6">
    <f:facet name="label">
        <h:outputText value="#{messages['test']}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText name="test"/>
</app:formField>
```

to this output :

```
<app:formField type="display" styleClass="col-6" label="#{messages['test']}">
    <h:inputText name="test"/>
</app:formField>
```

(adding a label property and removing f:facet name="label")

How can I achieve this with XSLT ? I tried multiple ideas but none are working :(

Thanks !

Comment: In this question, jsf does mot play any role. Just the xhtml as xml and not on the jsf context. And please post what you tried (which is required on SO)

Answer (score 0):

As an example I took your part of XML as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
    <app:formField type="display" styleClass="col-6">
        <f:facet name="label">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['test']}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText name="test"/>
    </app:formField> 
</root>
```

Then in XSL can be used defined required attribute set and use it for `<app:formField>` block as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
                xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" 
                xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <!--create attribute structure as by requirements-->
    <xsl:attribute-set name="formField-attr-set">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(/root/app:formField/@type)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/app:formField/@type"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="{name(/root/app:formField/@styleClass)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/app:formField/@styleClass"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:attribute name="{/root/app:formField/f:facet/@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/app:formField/f:facet/h:outputText/@value"/>
        </xsl:attribute>               
    </xsl:attribute-set>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <!--apply already defined attribute set-->
            <xsl:element name="app:formField" use-attribute-sets="formField-attr-set">
               <xsl:copy-of select="/root/app:formField/h:inputText"/>
            </xsl:element>          
        </root>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <app:formField type="display" styleClass="col-6" label="#{messages['test']}">
        <h:inputText name="test"/>
    </app:formField>
</root>
```